# multiple root access with own history

Tags: root, fingerprint

I want to get the publickey fingerprint of the user actualy logging in, to identify which user logging in as root, so i can create a bashrc for every user in a subfolder e.g. "/root/[FINGERPRINT]/.bashrc". How can I do that?
We don't want to use sudo!!!!

When I switch LogLevel of sshd to VERBOSE, I can see the fingerprint in the auth.log/sercure, but i guess that won't help.

We are using CentOS 6/7/8

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page: *all* of your users are logging in as root, and you feel this is a good decision and want to keep it this way?

Comment: Multiple users sharing direct access to `root` via ssh is anti-pattern, so it would be good to know a bit more about why you are working this way (IE why it's necessary).  Also, what's the objection to `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as asked (others have commented about if this is desirable).

Change the ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys to prepend `environment="RUSER=Chris"` before Chris's key, `environment="RUSER=Pete"` before Pete's key and so on. Lines should look something like

```
environment="RUSER=Pete" ssh-rsa AAAAB[snipped] pete@somewhere
```

Edit the sshd config file (usually /etc/ssh/sshd_config) to include a line

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

to enable environment processing. Get the `sshd` to reread the config file (I used `ps -ef | grep sshd\ -D` to find the PID and then used `kill -HUP PID` to get the daemon to reread the file.

At this point when you log in via ssh there will be an environment variable `RUSER` that can be used to tell which key was used to log in.

As environment variables can now be set, a careful audit should be made of the shell startup files to ensure that there are no undesired effects that can be triggered by unexpected values in environment variables.

This information is in the [sshd(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sshd.8.html) man pages in the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section.